# error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of C++. I am reading a book about C++. I use g++ to compile the following program, which is an example in the book:

```
/*modified fig1-1.cpp*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "\n Enter an integer";
    cin >> (int i);
    cout << "\n Enter a character";
    cin >> (char c);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I get the following error messages:

```
fig1-2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
fig1-2.cpp:7:10: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  cin >> (int i);
          ^
fig1-2.cpp:7:10: error: expected ')' before 'int'
fig1-2.cpp:9:10: error: expected primary-expression before 'char'
  cin >> (char c);
          ^
fig1-2.cpp:9:10: error: expected ')' before 'char'
```

Could anyone please tell me what happend? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: No...declare `int i` on one line _first_, then do `cin >> i` on a second line.

Comment: Is this *really* accurately copied from the book? If so, you need a different book.

Comment: @AnT This is really copied from the book, with some modification. The orignial codes is as follows: `/*modified fig1-1.cpp*/
#include <iostream.h>
void main()
{
    cout << "\n Enter an integer";
    cin >> (int i);
    cout << "\n Enter a character";
    cin >> (char c);
}` The reason why I modified the code is to avoid errors during compilation. OK, I will change to a different book.

Comment: @Wei-Cheng Liu: This `cin >> (int i)` bit is... just... I have no idea how anyone with at least basic understanding of C++ could write something like that.

Comment: @AnT Yes...I change to a new C++ book--C++ Premier 2nd Edition, and I begin to read it today.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int i` is the syntax for a declaration. It may not appear inside an expression, which should follow `cin >>`.

First declare your variable and then use it:

```
int i;
cin >> i;
```

The same for `char c`:

```
chat c;
cin >> c;
```

And I heavily doubt that this is an example in a book teaching C++. It is blatantly wrong syntax. If it really is in the book as a supposedly working example (i.e. not to explain the error), then you should get a different book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is an example in a book teaching C++, with some modification. The orignial codes is as follows: `/*modified fig1-1.cpp*/ #include <iostream.h> void main() { cout << "\n Enter an integer"; cin >> (int i); cout << "\n Enter a character"; cin >> (char c); }` The reason why I modified the code is to avoid errors during the compilation. OK, I will get a different book.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu Yeah `#include <iostream.h>` is also blatantly wrong and as you have seen any beginner will know that after writing their first program. `void main()` is accepted by some compilers, but is wrong, too. The missing `std::` before `cout` and `cin` is also obvious. You solved that with `using namespace std;` which works but often leads to problems further down the line. The book's author must never have compiled any of their code...

Answer (score 0):

you can not use as you are doing you will have to declare i or c first as i have done so

```
int main()
{
int i;
char c;
cout << "\n Enter an integer";
cin >> (i);
cout << "\n Enter a character";
cin >> (c);
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: A code-only answer? Why did you not provide an explanation for the code? It might be obvious for you, but not for a C++ beginner.